# How to generate minute-level data from Level 2 streaming data?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb, candlestick-chart

I would like to know if DolphinDB provides any available script for generating minute-level data (such as OHLC bars) from Level 2 streaming data. And since OHLC bars are generated based on the fixed time intervals, it is challenging to handle the financial instruments or securities with intermittent trading activity.

Can someone provide insights on how to address this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `createTimeSeriesEngine` to generate OHLC bars. For more details, see https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/30844e7b5ca3e51b2ec23c8138e361c39b0f84dd/OHLC.md#2-real-time-calculation

To handle less active instruments, you can configure the parameter *forceTriggerTime* or *updateTime* to trigger calculations. For more information, refer to [createTimeSeriesEngine — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/c/createTimeSeriesEngine.html#createtimeseriesengine).

One more point to note is:

The windows of different instruments are grouped together based on the time intervals. If any of the instruments within a particular time window have data available, it will trigger the closing of the associated windows, including those of less active instruments.